# Caused by: org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler found for GET /null/swagger-resources/configuration/ui

Tags: swagger-ui

Getting the below exception while starting the spring boot application.

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException: No handler found for GET /null/swagger-resources/configuration/ui
```

Swagger gradle dependencies versions are as below

```
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.7.0')
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.7.0')
```

Answer (score 2):

you need close like this browser tab.

my spring boot application port is 8888, when i close this tab and restart my spring boot application, the error is gone.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully it is the issue with **IntelliJ** editor. I'm running multiple microservices on different ports and shutting them down once the work is done, but IJ editor might have cached the port(which it already shut down) and causing this confusion and error. I have restarted the service with a different port, and the error is gone.

**Note:** In general, we will get ***BIND ERROR : Address already in use***, if any other service is running on the same port.